# Sitecore Ajax post returning same page

Tags: ajax

I've trying to make a POST request. It is returning the same page, i.e the whole HTML instead of the result I send via the Controller.

```
@model kgSitecoreTraining.Models.BlogVotes



<div class="blog-vote">

        <div id="vote-form">
            <input type="button" class="up" id="up" name="up" value=@Model.Up>
            <input type="button" class="down" id="down" name="down" value=@Model.Down>
        </div>

</div>
<script>

    window.addEventListener('load',
        function () {
             $('#up').on('click', function (event) {
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: window.location.href,
                context: this,
                data: "{ scController: 'BlogVotes', scAction: 'test', option: 'op'}",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert(error);
                    console.dir(error);
                }
                 });
            event.preventDefault();
        });
        }, false);
</script>
```

And this is the controller

```
using kgSitecoreTraining.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Sitecore.Links;
using Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Helpers;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace kgSitecoreTraining.Controllers
{
    public class BlogVotesController : Controller
    {
        // GET: BlogVotes
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(CreateModel());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult test(string option)
        {
            return Json(option);

        }

        private BlogVotes CreateModel() {
            var item = RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Item;
            var model = new BlogVotes()
            {
                Up = Int32.Parse(item["Up"]),
                Down = Int32.Parse(item["Down"]),
                UrlPost = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item).ToString()
            };
            return model;
        }
    }
}
```

As I said, instead of returning the JSON, It's returning the HTML. Any Idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my point of view it's not a correct way for call your api.
Try to sent your request in another way:
instead of `window.location.href`
try to call `http://{hostname}/api/sitecore/BlogVotes/test` via HTTP POST

Comment: Agree completely. Example could look like this: `$.post('/api/sitecore/DropdownCart/RemoveLine', { lineId: lineId })`

Comment: Thanks so much, it worked. Still dont know why the old way return the same page.

Comment: Great! When you are trying to send request to `window.location.href`, Sitecore resolves your request as a request for render Sitecore item and runs pipelines for render item. Also you can register new route and call your api based on route settings.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to explain. I understand now. Awesome!